# Oracle - Display 'No Rows' when query returns no results

Tags: sql, oracle, sqlplus

I would like my Oracle SQL output to display 'No Rows Found' when the query returns no results.

I am trying to use the NVL function but Im getting an error stating

> 'ERROR at line 21: ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis'

```
SELECT NVL((
            SELECT TO_CHAR(CHGDATE, 'yyyy-mm')
                ,CHGFIELD
                ,DBNAME
                ,COUNT(*)
            FROM APPCHANGEHIST A
                ,DATABASEFIELD D
            WHERE A.CHGFIELD = D.FIELDNUM
                AND trunc(CHGDATE) BETWEEN add_months(to_date(to_char((sysdate - to_char(sysdate, 'dd') + 1), 'dd-mon-yyyy')), - 1)
                    AND to_date(to_char((sysdate - to_char(sysdate, 'dd')), 'dd-mon-yyyy'))
                AND CHGFIELD = 79
                AND OLDVALUE IS NOT NULL
                AND EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM USERPROF
                    WHERE USERID = A.CHGREQUESTOR
                    )
            GROUP BY TO_CHAR(CHGDATE, 'yyyy-mm')
                ,CHGFIELD
                ,DBNAME
            ORDER BY 1
                ,4 DESC
            ), "No Rows");
```

I don't have issues when I run this statement alone without the NVL

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(CHGDATE, 'yyyy-mm')
                ,CHGFIELD
                ,DBNAME
                ,COUNT(*)
            FROM APPCHANGEHIST A
                ,DATABASEFIELD D
            WHERE A.CHGFIELD = D.FIELDNUM
                AND trunc(CHGDATE) BETWEEN add_months(to_date(to_char((sysdate - to_char(sysdate, 'dd') + 1), 'dd-mon-yyyy')), - 1)
                    AND to_date(to_char((sysdate - to_char(sysdate, 'dd')), 'dd-mon-yyyy'))
                AND CHGFIELD = 79
                AND OLDVALUE IS NOT NULL
                AND EXISTS (
                    SELECT 1
                    FROM USERPROF
                    WHERE USERID = A.CHGREQUESTOR
                    )
            GROUP BY TO_CHAR(CHGDATE, 'yyyy-mm')
                ,CHGFIELD
                ,DBNAME
            ORDER BY 1
                ,4 DESC
```

Comment: Unfortunately, NVL only works when your query returns a NULL value for a row.  If it is returning no rows, you need a different solution.

Comment: Unrelated, but: `add_months(to_date(to_char((sysdate - to_char(sysdate, 'dd') + 1), 'dd-mon-yyyy')), - 1)` can be simplified to `add_months(trunc(sysdate), - 1)`

Comment: Do it at the presentation level (i.e. in your app), not at the SQL level.

Comment: As an aside, your handling of dates is so wrong in so many ways.  sysdate is a DATE, so 'sysdate - to_char(sysdate, 'dd')' is subtracting a string from a DATE.  Oracle will attempt proper type conversion, but that will depend on NLS settings to get it right.  And you repeat this fundamental error several times.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out.  Admittedly I am coming into this only to fix the problem where it displays nothing under a heading if data does not exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, at a high level, you can use the following pattern:

```sql
WITH results AS
(
  SELECT *
  FROM dual d
  WHERE d.dummy = 'Y'
)
SELECT *
FROM results
UNION ALL
SELECT 'No Rows Found'
FROM dual
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 'X'
                  FROM results);
```

You can play with this by changing the value in the WITH clause between 'X' and 'Y'.
In your query, you would just replace the SELECT within the WITH clause with your query.

Comment: I should note, this only currently works because `DUAL` only has one column.  If your WITH clause has more than one column, you will need to match the number of columns in the second part of the UNION ALL.  This can be done by adding `NULL` in the additional columns.

Comment: Im sorry, I dont understand how this ties into the current SQL I have.

Comment: @salazar44 Take your current SQL (The one that works, without the NVL) and replace `SELECT * from DUAL WHERE d.dummy = 'Y'`.  If rows are returned, they will be returned as normal.  If no rows are returned, the message 'No Rows Found' will be returned instead. (As I mentioned above, you'll need to add NULL columns for the 'No Rows Found' query so that the column count matches your other query.